# Sorting by Number in sqlite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sorting

In SqLite Database i have Door Number, I Want Sort Like Below
For Example :

```
1
2
3
3/1
3/2
4
5
6/2
```

I Need to Show Short Like That
Thanks in Advance

Comment: add 'ORDER BY door_no ASC' to your query

Comment: `ASC` is the default. Therefore, you can omit it. `ORDER BY door_no` is enough.

Comment: These values obviously are strings, so a simple `ORDER BY` will not work.

Comment: 3/1 is string string so Order By is Not Working